# Destructuration with imports and Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm building the type system of @masala/parser, so I can edit the index.d.ts as I want.

As a user, I can do:

```
import masala from '@masala/parser'
let {C, Stream, F} = masala;
```

but I can't do what is the common way in ES2015:

```
import {C, Stream, F} from '@masala/parser'
```

TS2305: module has no exported member C (neither Stream or F)

I have tried to put all I can in the `index.d.ts`:

```
interface MasalaBundlesStatic{
    Stream?: StreamFactory,
    C?: CharBundle,
    F?: FlowBundle,
    N?:NumberBundle,
}

declare const F:FlowBundle;
declare const C:CharBundle;
declare const Streams:StreamFactory;
declare const N:NumberBundle;
declare const MasalaBundles :MasalaBundlesStatic;
export default MasalaBundles;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the members individually.

i.e.

```
interface MasalaBundlesStatic{
    Stream?: StreamFactory,
    C?: CharBundle,
    F?: FlowBundle,
    N?:NumberBundle,
}

export const F:FlowBundle;
export const C:CharBundle;
export const Streams:StreamFactory;
export const N:NumberBundle;
export const MasalaBundles :MasalaBundlesStatic;
export default MasalaBundles;
```

Or something similar to that.

Comment: In fact yes, that's what is written in the error message :D